# How to get a response of custom action in react admin

Tags: react-admin

I dispatch a custom action in react admin after a click on Upload button. POST request successfully works, but I don't know how to get a response. I log every reducer call, but no response data there. Example of my action:

```
export const UPLOAD_BY_BASE64 = 'UPLOAD_BY_BASE64';
export const uploadByBase64 = ({ file, path }) => ({
  type: UPLOAD_BY_BASE64,
  payload: { file, path },
  meta: { fetch: CREATE, resource: 'images/upload/base64' }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Handling Side Effects documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Actions.html#handling-side-effects), you can pass a callback to the meta attribute in order to retrieve the response payload:

```js
export const uploadByBase64 = ({ file, path }) => ({
  type: UPLOAD_BY_BASE64,
  payload: { file, path },
  meta: {
    fetch: CREATE,
    resource: 'images/upload/base64',
    callback: ({ payload, requestPayload }) => {
      // payload = response payload
    },
  },
});
```